# Simple Pong build with SpriteKit in Swift5. Wired spikes formed between paddles

Tags: xcode, macos, swift5, macos-catalina

I'm creating this simple Pong game. Two paddles on bottom and top. One ball bouncing around.

When it runs, the paddle has formed wired spikes poking around the field.

**Code:** GameScene.swift

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

//create obj

var ball = SKSpriteNode()
var enemy = SKSpriteNode()
var main = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    ball = self.childNode(withName: "ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    enemy = self.childNode(withName: "enemy") as! SKSpriteNode
    main = self.childNode(withName: "main") as! SKSpriteNode

    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:20, dy:20)   )

    let border = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)

    border.friction = 0
    border.restitution = 1

    self.physicsBody = border
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
}
```

- OS: Mac Catalina
- Xcode 11.2(11B52)
- Swift 5

Wondering if this is a rendering issue.

Any Idea?
[Record of spikes](https://youtu.be/uUrCkbD51Gg)

Comment: Hi, please do not use code screenshots. Update your question with your actual code and error logs if any.

Comment: @SudheeshR Looks great now, thx

Comment: Welcome to SO! Don't use code screenshots, it is hard to check.

Comment: Not yet, remove the image and update with your actual code block.